# Multiline names (x labels) in boxplot

Tags: r, data-visualization, boxplot

In `R`, I would like to give multiline names to some data sets in `boxplot`, like this:

```
boxplot(rnorm(10), rnorm(10, mean=2), names=c("Normal", "Shifted\n*"))
```

Here, the names seem to be aligned with their bottom lines, which causes the text to overlap with the axis.  How can I have multiline names which simply extend to the bottom instead of upwards?

Comment: Hi quazgar. The question seems to be only about R which makes it off-topic here but on-topic on [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: After reading the **R** tag info, I agree.  Can the question be moved over or should I add the question there manually?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to do what you want, or at least very close:

```
boxplot(rnorm(10), rnorm(10, mean=2))
mtext(text=c("Normal", "Shifted\n*"),
      side = 1, line = c(2,3), at = c(1,2))
```